# Is it possible to define type cast operator for non-structural (esp. numeric) types?

Tags: c++

For struct or class I'm able to define own type conversion operator as a member:

```
FOO operator FOO(BAR b);
```

Is there any way to do it for non-structural types, for example something like this:

```
int operator int(float x);
```

?

Comment: A conversion operator must be a member function taking no arguments. It also doesn't have an explicit return type (it's implied). So I'm not sure what your first declaration is supposed to be.

Comment: According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/general-rules-for-operator-overloading?view=vs-2019):You cannot redefine the meaning of operators when applied to built-in data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [CPP Official Reference document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), operator overlaoding (cast operator as well) is defined as below:

> Enables implicit conversion or explicit conversion from a class type to another type.

Which means, the answer is NO.

If you think about it, that seems a valid rule. There wont be a reason to redefine `int + int` for mainly the following 2 reaons:

1. Compiler already provides the default and geric support for the same
2. You cannot redefine the meaning of operators when applied to built-in data types.

Answer (score 4):

You can always box your FOO type, in case Foo is int:

```
class MyInt {
    public:
        int value;
};
```

Then implement your `MyInt operator(float x);` inside `MyInt` class.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to define conversions from non class type to another. Only way to define conversions are member functions, which can only be defined for classes.